# numerical wildcard in LIKE query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a lot of names followed by a number. All entries use the same syntax, but some names have numbers from 1 up to 99

example:

```
john 1
john 2
john 3
john smith 1
john smith 2
```

In this example, i'm trying to select all "john" entries

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE 'john %'
```

The problem is that it will also select entries from "john smith". How can i avoid that ? Is it possible to use some kind of wildcard to do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE 'john [0-9]'
```

Comment: You could use REGEXP aka [RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: the manual knows all: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: ouch, looks complicated :/ what regex do i need to use to match numerical values (0-99) ?

Comment: `[0-9]{1,2}`, probably. but that would  alllow stuff like `03`, which you may or may not want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) it seems the simplest query would be:

```
select * from tablename where name REGEXP '^john smith [[:digit:]]{1,2}$';
```

which will limit the expression to having at most 2 digits, thus effectively limiting it to 0-99.

Or

```
select * from tablename where name REGEXP '^john smith [[:digit:]]+$';
```

which won't limit it to 0-99 but will allow any combination of digits after the space.

Note that if you don't include the `^` at the beginning then things like "x john smith 2" would be allowed. And if you don't include the `$` at the end, then "john smith 2 x" would be allowed.

To capture both john and john smith would require something more like:

```
select * from tablename where name REGEXP '^john [[:alpha:]]{0,}[[:space:]]{0,1}[[:digit:]]{1,2}$' ;
```

The `{n,n}` is the min and max times for repeating the element.  So for "john" we will not have this alpha element but for "john smith" we will have one set of alpha letters, hence the `{0,}` meaning minimum 0 alpha characters and no max. The same for space since with "john" we won't have this space. But probably we want to limit the number of spaces that can occur here to 1, hence the max part is included `{0,1}`.

Comment: This would be the traditional way of doing it, bear in mind the OP wanted `'^john [[:digit:]]{1,2}$'` but that is easily adjusted.

Comment: @Arth, I missed the part about wanting it to work for both john and john smith. Have corrected that oversight.

Comment: Seems good, but is there a way to add a wildcard after the numerical value ? So it can match results like John 1.png, John 1.gif, John 1.jpg, etc

Comment: you could add a literal dot with [[.period.]] and then i.e. a list of allowed file extensions png|gif|jpg to the pattern.

Comment: so what would be the full regex to use instead of '^john smith [[:digit:]]+$'

Comment: As I said, it would be `'^john smith[[:digit:]]{1,2}[[.period.]]gif|png|jpg$'` to match the file extensions gif, png or jpg (nothing else, no tiff, no jpeg or others).

Comment: doesn't work, it returns over 500 results from my database that doesn't even contain the words "john smith" or digits http://gyazo.com/5df0cce7694910b3632929b03ae70d31

Comment: I missed the parentheses around the file extensions, should be `REGEXP '^john smith[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]{1,2}[[.period.]](gif|png|jpg)$'` because else you match everything that ends with jpg :-)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything like that for `LIKE` but you can use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

You'll probably get the best performance from:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE name LIKE 'john %'
   AND 0 < SUBSTR(name,6)
```

This'll convert the second part of the string into a number and see if it is greater than 0, anything that starts with a letter will be converted to 0.

The LIKE in this case can still use an index on `name`.

I would definitely question your data structure too, the number after the name should really be in a separate numerical column. Come to think of it, the surname 'Smith' should be in a separate column too!

Comment: this wont work for the other examples the OP posted aka 'john smith 1'